# Extract notes from Microsoft office powerpoint files using PDFtron webviewer library in angular

Tags: angular, powerpoint, pdftron

We have an angular app where we want to render Microsoft Office PowerPoint(.pptx) slides by using [PDFtron webviewer library](https://www.pdftron.com/api/web/index.html). In our existing .pptx files some slides contain **notes** with them and we want to show those notes in PDFTron webviewer UI along with the slides. But the problem is when webviewer UI render the slides it doesn't show the notes associated with them.
We have explored the events and properties of **DocumentViewer**, **AnnotationManager**, **CoreControls.Document**, etc. API references to get the notes of each slide. But no desired output is found.

As the library is huge to explore, are there any properties/events callback in webviewer API to get **notes** of each slide in an **existing .pptx** file? Please suggest if any.

Answer (score 1):

At the moment, we do not have any property/events callbacks in our WebViewer API to get notes of each slide in .pttx files.

We are actively looking into this right now, and anticipate having something available on around the 3-4 month timeframe.